# How to find out a user's previous Active Directory usernames?

Tags: .net, active-directory

I'm working on a user permissions system for an internal admin webapp. I had the idea to use user's ActiveDirectory guids to match permissions with users instead of using their usernames. This is done in case they change their username - I've been assured this will happen often enough.

Then I started to wonder: instead of worrying about the guid and using it to resolve their username, does ActiveDirectory keep a record of previous usernames?

If it did, when an unknown user tries to connect, we can check if their previous username has permissions set up and update the database with their username automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Active Directory does not keep a history of prior user names. Using the GUID is absolutely the best thing that you can do.

In fact, when our company ran into a similar issue several years ago, we ended up building our own "AD Snapshot Writer" that would poll AD periodically for the changes, calculate deltas, and store the results for the attributes that we needed (user name, e-mail addresses, etc.) in a database with [*temporal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database) attributes.

Comment: I thought as much. The temporal database is a cool idea, but if we store the user guid in addition to the username in our local table, it won't offer anything extra.

Comment: @user1800482 Our project needed a temporal database only for running audits. GUID was sufficient for the day-to-day tasks of checking permissions.

Comment: I hope you use DirSync for the polling?

Comment: @EricFleischman We programmed directly to AD-specific API for mirroring (obtaining a token, getting the deltas, reconstructing the results from the deltas, and so on).

Comment: Yea, I'm asking how you are getting the delta from AD. The most efficient way to ask AD for deltas is called DirSync. It is an AD capability exposed over LDAP.

Comment: @EricFleischman I see. I did not code that part of the project, so I don't know how that API is called. I worked on the temporal storage for the back end of this component.

Comment: Gotcha. Well if you decide to make it more efficient feel free to reach out. DirSync is the way to do it. It is a capability exposed over LDAP, in the form of an LDAP control. Though it is tricky to do correctly, so you need to be sure you have the right underlying assumptions or you will get in to trouble.